# Adding iFrame to Flash website

Tags: flash, iframe, flash-cs5

I have a website that I am creating in Flash CS5.  There are several different pages of context and each of these pages are loaded from it's own XML file.  I am trying to figure out how to add an iFrame to one of these pages.  Specifically, I am trying to add the Facebook Like Box to a page and I figured the iFrame would be the best way to do it.

Any suggestions on where I should go from here or suggestions on different directions I could look into?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm) may be helpful, it contains demo and code. (it is a little bit old but useful.)
Also you may want to read [Don't Use IFrames for HTML in Flex](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/07/dont_use_iframe.htm). There is a paid component here: [Html Component](http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent).

Additionally, you can always try getting contents of your Facebook Like Box script source (for example you can get it with curl, pycurl, wget etc.), parse it on server side, make it XML and send to Flash. You can see [Flash Facebook Like Box](http://activeden.net/item/flash-facebook-like-box/149004) and its demo [here](http://flashfx.site90.net/likebox/).